# Flutter adaptiveness ( Font Size issue on different screen )

Tags: flutter

Can Anyone help me how can I adjust my flutter app according to screensize.

Any formula using device pixelratio or any method will help. This always my dilemma when im making flutter app

Comment: I leave font size to the textTheme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **aspect ratio** for the different sizes of the devices.

```
Container(
      color: Colors.blue,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      width: double.infinity,
      height: 100.0,
      child: AspectRatio(
        aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.green,
        ),
      ),
    );
```

You can also use **media query** to get the height and width of the device so you can easily modify UI accordingly

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     
    // getting the size of the window
    size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    height = size.height;
    width = size.width;
 
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Geeks For Geeks"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
      ),
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.yellow,
        height: height/2,//half of the height size
        width: width/2,//half of the width size
      ),
    );
  }
```